# Running funkload tests located in some folder

Tags: python, funkload

I have the following project structure:

```
funkload_configs
 - Simple.conf
a
 - __init__.py
 - module1.py
 - perf_tests
   - __init__.py
   - perf_test1.py
```

when I run `fl-run-test -dv perf_tests/perf_test1.py` from project root (the one containing `funkload_configs` and `a` folders) I get the following error:

`ImportError: No module named perf_test1`

Is it possible to run a funkload test located in another directory?

I've also set the `FL_CONF_PATH` environment variable to point to `funkload_configs`

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the path of your funk load scripts. Ex: `C:\Python27\Scripts\fl-run-test-script.py`. Then you can run a test script located in `C:\MyTestscripts\ABC.py` as:

   `C:\Python27\Scripts\fl-run-test-script.py C:\MyTestscripts\ABC.py`
2. Or Edit Path in your Environment variables: Add `C:\Python27\Scripts`. Then you can run tests from anywhere.